# Problems with Admin CP after updating from v2.2.2 to v2.10.1

Tags: control-panel, update

After the update the Admin CP is not working properly anymore.
The 'Edit' under 'Content' dropdown is broken. Alle the labels have cpmm_ as prefix. And the links are linking to new pages instead of edit.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Grtz,
Martijn

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing is almost always an issue with a failed upload during the upgrade process. Those labels (cpmm whatever) exist because the language file is missing those entries in a PHP array.

EE language method replacement fails back to the array key when it can't find a `key => val` pair.

Did you make sure you followed the upgrade instructions exactly? Try reuploading your system folder. I could tell you the exact file if I was at my desk.

Comment: I did follow the upgrade instructions exactly. I did a new upgrade and after that the same problems where there. The only thing I can imagine then is that the 'old' website had missing files in the first place and after updating giving problems?!

I would be very pleased to know what exact file is missing here.

Thanks in advance!

Grtz, Martijn

Comment: It's worth clearing your browser cache as well.

Comment: I now know what the problem was... Dev mode